# Calculating percentages of a factor variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate percentages/counts of each level of a factor variable in a data frame within dplyr, kind of like using table, and while I can do this manually, this becomes tedious if I have many factor variables or the factor variable has many levels.

Example:

```
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(groupbyvar = LETTERS[1:4],
               var1 = letters[1:4],
               var2 = as.factor(sample(1:4,12,TRUE)))

data %>% group_by(groupbyvar) %>% summarise(var1_a = mean(var1 == 'a', na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_b = mean(var1 == 'b', na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_c = mean(var1 == 'c', na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_d = mean(var1 == 'd', na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_1 = mean(var2 == 1, na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_2 = mean(var2 == 2, na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_3 = mean(var2 == 3, na.rm=TRUE),
                                        var1_4 = mean(var2 == 4, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I thought about using table, but this doesn't generate output that dplyr can understand. Also, I thought about using something like model.matrix to generate indicators on the factor variables before passing in the dataframe, but this increases memory footprint unnecessarily (esp for a large data set). Is there some easy way to automate this?

The result should be a new dataframe with percentages/counts:

```
  groupbyvar var1_a var1_b var1_c var1_d    var1_1    var1_2    var1_3    var1_4
1          A      1      0      0      0 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000
2          B      0      1      0      0 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
3          C      0      0      1      0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333
4          D      0      0      0      1 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333
```

I want it to automate the suffix on each column name, similar to what model.matrix does with factor variables.

Comment: Is `group_by(data, groupbyvar) %>% summarise_each(funs(n()))` what you're looking for?  Showing us the desired result would help

Comment: Not sure if the format returned here will work for you but, `tapply(data$var1, INDEX = data$groupbyvar, table)
tapply(data$var2, INDEX = data$groupbyvar, table)`

Comment: @RichardScriven, the summarise_each function only produces one output column per function, I would like it to produce one column for each level of the factor.

Comment: Try using `tidyr` in the end you can reshape it back up to one per column.  Also ... I'm not sure exactly what happens if you don't send it to latex but the truth is `tablular` will definitely give you what you want in terms of data.

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. Why are you running `mean(var1 == 'b', na.rm=TRUE)` 7 times? How do they differ from each other? Maybe your just looking for `library(reshape2) ; dcast(data, groupbyvar ~ var1 + var2)`?

Comment: Now you removed your data set. Please return it and don't forget to add `set.seed` as you are using `sample`

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip @DavidArenburg, It must have gotten deleted while I was copy pasting. Here it is, the dcast function doesn't produce the same output, it leaves out factor combinations that don't occur.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely overly complicated but I do think that `tables` will do what you probably want.

Your data

```
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(groupbyvar = LETTERS[1:4],
                    var1 = letters[1:4],
                    var2 = as.factor(sample(1:4,12,TRUE)))
```

Then we put it into `tabular`.

```
mytab<-tabular( (Factor(groupbyvar, "Group") + 1)*( 
    (ColPct=Percent("col")))
    ~  (Factor(var1, "var1")
        + Factor(var2, "var2")  + 
            1)
    *Format(digits=1), data=data )
```

Which gives me myTab

```
           var1             var2                
 Group        a    b   c   d   1    2   3   4   All
 A     ColPct 100    0   0   0   0   40  33   0  25
 B     ColPct   0  100   0   0  50   40   0   0  25
 C     ColPct   0    0 100   0   0    0  67  50  25
 D     ColPct   0    0   0 100  50   20   0  50  25
 All   ColPct 100  100 100 100 100  100 100 100 100
```

And then extract the data from myTab  (e.g. `class(table(myTab))` is table. It is really a pain though.

Comment: Thanks for answering it, I will upvote but not checkmark since this will create too large of a memory footprint to efficiently solve the problem. Really what I'm looking for is some kind of way to automatically generate syntax that I can feed into the summarise function without having to type out all the levels of the factor variables.

Comment: So all you really want to do is to generate `var1_1 = mean(var2 == 1, na.rm=TRUE)`  and you have an array of variable names and array of unique values for each of the variables, right?

Comment: yes, just when the number of variables is big or the number of levels of the factor is big it becomes a pain in the butt to write them all out manually, so I thought there would be an easy way to automate this but haven't figured this out yet.